# X-Forwarding on server

Tags: ssh, unix, remote

It is possible to use `X11-forwarding` running on a common `remote server without GPU` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

X11-Forwarding does not require any kind of graphics ability on the host, and is commonly used in this configuration (among many others no doubt) when remotely maintaining VM's.  [ If you are using Linux, the only thing you need installed on the remote host by way of an "X" environment is xauth, and possibly some fonts - you don't even need X installed].